# Apache camel passing header value from xml to .properties

Tags: properties, apache-camel

I use apache camel to run sql which is configured in .properties

I use Postgresql. I have partitions on my table which i would like to truncate dynamically.

## XML

```
<!--set the year of a month ago in header type Int, 
if not type int, i faced an error PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter -->

             <setHeader name="year">
                 <groovy>java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.time.LocalDate.now().minus(1, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MONTHS).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy")))</groovy>
             </setHeader>


<!--create a temporary table and insert into from table_exempleA with mentioned year(header value) in where clause.
header value year is well interpreted in where clause-->
            <to uri="sql:{{temp.create.insert.query}}?dataSource=#exempleCamelDataSource" />

<!--truncate table_exempleA with partition -->
            <to uri="sql:{{truncate.query}}?dataSource=#exempleCamelDataSource" />
```

## .properties

```
# header value by using :#year are well interpreted in where clause. 
# I simplify below query to understand easily.

temp.create.insert.query=\
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS \
SELECT * FROM table_exempleA \
WHERE date_part('year', date) = :#year


# Facing an issue here, :#year is not well interpreted.
truncate.query=\
  TRUNCATE TABLE table_exempleA_:#year
```

I am facing issues when i truncate table with header value which present partition value.
Error --> PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1

so what i tried is to set "year" value as type String

```
        <setHeader name="year">
            <simple resultType="String">${headers.year}</simple>
        </setHeader>
```

Still having same error by using type String.

I tried also to put sql in `<to uri>` with header value in type String like below :

```
<to uri="sql:TRUNCATE TABLE table_exempleA_:#${headers.year}?dataSource=#testCamelDataSource" />
```

String having same error : PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1

I've been trying everything i could find on the internet but haven't found yet..
Could you please help me to find away to truncate table dynamically ?